# How can I exclude certain folders from being indexed by search engines in ASP.net when SSL is forced?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, robots.txt

Good day,

I've done some research looking for this answer, but haven't had much luck. Hoping someone can help..

The situation is that a site I'm working on (built in ASP.net) which forces SSL on most of their pages has some folders (ie. `site.com/dontindex` )containing files that definitely shouldn't be indexed by search engines. Google has links to these files in its index (ie. `https://www.site.com/dontindex/file.pdf`).

My issue is that I have created a robots.txt file to disallow those folders from indexing, but from what I've read, that isn't going to prevent those files being indexed - as some of them might be referenced through secure pages. I'm thinking that only the non-secure pages are disallowed in this way. **Q1) Is that even correct?**

When I tested `http://www.site.com/dontindex/file.pdf` against the new robots file in Google Webmaster Tools, wit came back as "Blocked by line 5: Disallow: /dontindex/", but when I tried `https://www.site.com/dontindex/file.pdf` it came back as "Not in domain".

From what I can gather, I should have a second robots.txt file somewhere for the secure files/folders. I've read that if the site were running php, I could do some sort of a rewrite rule to cover this, but what to do in my ASP.net situation?? **Q2) If it applies to me to have a second robots file (given that it's an ASP.net site), where should I put this file?**

Thank-you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is more to do with the Google webmaster tools, as `http://site.com/robots.txt == https://site.com/robots.txt`

The not in domain error is I think because Google classes the 2 as separate sites. You need to add the https and http sites to check the robots file.

Comment: Thank-you! I added the site with the secure prefix (it asked me to confirm ownership/control by uploading the same html file as the non-secure prefix incidentally). I then tested a link to a file that is listed (but shouldn't be), and it says that the same robots file disallows its listing. Perfect! I have resubmitted the site for indexing so those unwanted listings should fade away eventually (right??).